# Fullcalendarのリスト表示時に降順にする方法

Tags: fullcalendar

ウェブページにカレンダーを表示する"FullCalendar"というJsプラグインを使っているのですが、リスト表示させた際に日付が常に順番どおりに並んでしまうので、近い順（降順）にする方法を教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: これのことですかね？ > FullCalendar https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: 現在のコードを示して頂くことは可能でしょうか？　質問文下の「編集」から追記して頂ければと思います :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FullCalendarのList View及びeventOrderについてのドキュメントを参照しましたが、昇順・降順を変更する方法はなさそうです（eventOrderはソートする項目を選択するためのものであるようです）。

> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view
>   https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder

ですので、[List Viewの実装](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/list/ListView.ts)を参考に別途作成するしか無いように思われます。